# Taking float and integer input on single line

Tags: python

I tried this code to input an integer and a float number on the same line

```
withdraw,initial_bal = map(float if '.' in input() else int,input().split(' '))
```

But I am gettting an error could not convert string to float: ''
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Read a whole line, split the line, and convert each part separately. Now you try to read input twice, but only split one of those inputs.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide what error message you received.

Answer (score 0):

```
# inputting 3434 343.3
withdraw, initial_bal = (float(a) if '.' in a else int(a) for a in input().split())
print(withdraw, initial_bal)
>>3434 343.3
```